# Erro VB.NET DataGridView

Tags: winforms, vb.net

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro:

> There is no row at position 0

Alguem me sabe solucionar ou explicar o que é este erro?!

Comment: Mário, eu não estou certo de que seja isso, mas debugue seu programa e veja se idCliente é um valor válido. Certifique-se também que o DataSet que você retorna em 'LerEmpregadosByID' tem uma tabela com o nome 'empregados'

Comment: Bem vindo Mario Rui. Por favor, de sempre preferência por colocar o texto do erro e seu código ao invés da imagem. Aproveitando, faça o [Tour] e conheça melhor a comunidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro quer dizer exatamente oque está escrito nele:

> Não há uma linha na posição zero

Para resolver também é simples: Antes de fazer a atribuição que está na linha do erro, valide se a linha que está acessando possui valor.

Use: [String.IsNullOrEmpty(minhaString)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3).

Comment: obrigado. consegui resolver.

Comment: Que bom @MarioRui, se a resposta te ajudou marque ela no simbolo a esquerda ou você pode adicionar sua própria resposta se achar válido.